# Installing OpenCV for Python 3 on Fedora 24

Tags: python, opencv, fedora

I followed very this carefully [makefile](https://gist.github.com/wuerges/b3c32dfcc6302aa1c105) and well, it finishes well.

On CMake output, there's this: **python(for build): 2.7** instead of **3.5**

But I read [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/) and I quote:

> You can ignore the “for build” section, that part of the CMake script
>   is buggy.

But after I finish compiling and installing:

```
$ python3

> import cv2
```

**ImportError: No module named 'cv2'**

What I am doing wrong? do I need to specify PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH, PYTHON3_LIBRARY, PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR? I want to install OpenCV system wide so I can symlink it and used it in any virtualenv that I might require opencv. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never used opencv but it is installed on my Fedora 24. Why don't you simply `dnf install opencv`?

Comment: @skytux thank you for your comment and that install it for Python 2 I assume, I require it with Python 3

Comment: You are right! Sorry for the noise...

Comment: Not a problem, if you find out the answer please come back with all the noise you want @skytux :)

Comment: Well, I have compiled OpenCV and it works under Python 3. Check my steps [here](http://paste.fedoraproject.org/401387/). I think you can make some comparisons.

Comment: I don't understand this line `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/german/Programs/test-install/usr/local/lib`, why? and also this other one `sys.path.append("/home/german/Programs/test-install/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/")` why or how did you figured that path? @skytux  I have no words to thank you for the time you're taking doing this! I appreciate it.

Comment: @skytux please don't misunderstand my last comment, I know what those lines do I just don't know how you figured the path... and the reason why we need to declare them isn't clear to me. I'm used to `sudo make install` and then `import cv2`. :/

Comment: I added an answer below. And please sorry for my poor English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some comments, I think that your problem may be with setting the path of the library. So, after compiling OpenCV (see [here](http://paste.fedoraproject.org/401387/)) I didn't install it on a default location on my system, I rather installed it in a local folder (it is easier to delete after this test), so I needed to provide the path to the library, that's why I did:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/german/Programs/test-install/usr/local/lib
```

Then I also need to tell python where the module is, because again it isn't in a default path, so I append the path of OpenCV to the path list:

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/home/german/Programs/test-install/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/")
```

You may want to check your python path after the append:

```
>>> sys.path
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib64/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/plat-linux',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/german/.ipython',
 '/home/german/Programs/test-install/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/']
```

Hope this helps to figure out your problem!

Comment: You have taught me many things in your comments and in your answer! I didn't even know you could change the directory where compiled programs should be installed. I got it installed now, and yes the whole problem was setting the path to the library. Now the only thing left is to add this permanently in `.bashrc`! Thanks again!